# Using VAAPI to play 1080p videos?

Tags: 11.04, vaapi

How can I use VAAPI to play 1080p videos with hardware acceleration in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an Intel card  install the `i965-va-driver` and `vainfo` packages. After that, issue the `vainfo` command, you should get something similar to this:

```
$ vainfo
libva: libva version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA API version: 0.32
vainfo: Driver version: i965 Driver 0.1
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Baseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

Answer (score -1):

Install your drivers for your video card, download xvba-video from http://www.splitted-desktop.com/static/libva/xvba-video/ if using ATI card install vlc from this ppa https://launchpad.net/~dtl131/+archive/catalysthacks

Comment: Thanks, my video card is Intel GMA HD (that comes integrated with Core i3). Will those work with it?